# SQL Select with REGEXP returning wrong rows of data

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using the following SELECT to get all the 2012 rushing plays from an NFL play by play database

```
Select gameid, season, off, description, qtr, down, ydstogoal 
FROM 2010_12pxp
WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE "%up the middle%" OR DESCRIPTION REGEXP "(left|right) (tackle|guard|end)" OR DESCRIPTION REGEXP " rushe(d|s) for "
AND season = 2012
GROUP BY id
```

However, it is returning ALL of the running plays in the database, not just those from 2012. Sample here:

```
gameid  season  off description qtr down    ydstogoal
20100909_MIN@NO 2010    NO  (13:36) R.Bush left end pushed ob at MIN 29 for 8 yards (M.Williams A.Allen).   1   2   37
20100909_MIN@NO 2010    MIN (12:56) A.Peterson right tackle to MIN 23 for 3 yards (R.Harper).   1   1   80
20100909_MIN@NO 2010    MIN (12:16) A.Peterson right tackle to MIN 28 for 5 yards (J.Vilma).    1   2   77
20100909_MIN@NO 2010    MIN (11:38) A.Peterson left guard to MIN 27 for -1 yards (S.Shanle J.Dunbar).   1   3   72
20100909_MIN@NO 2010    MIN (8:38) A.Peterson left tackle to MIN 41 for 2 yards (J.Vilma S.Shanle). 1   3   61
20100909_MIN@NO 2010    MIN (7:51) A.Peterson right end to NO 42 for 17 yards (R.Gay). PENALTY on MIN-V.Shiancoe Offensive Holding 10 yards enforced at MIN 41 - No Play.   1   2   59
```

How do I get it to filter by season (2012) and/or team only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use extra parentheses

```
Select gameid, season, off, description, qtr, down, ydstogoal 
FROM 2010_12pxp
WHERE 
(
   DESCRIPTION LIKE "%up the middle%" 
   OR DESCRIPTION REGEXP "(left|right) (tackle|guard|end)" 
   OR DESCRIPTION REGEXP " rushe(d|s) for "
)
AND season = 2012
GROUP BY id
```

If you **don't** then your query will be interpreted like this

```
WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE "%up the middle%" 
OR DESCRIPTION REGEXP "(left|right) (tackle|guard|end)" 
OR 
(
   DESCRIPTION REGEXP " rushe(d|s) for "
   AND season = 2012
)
```

Comment: I can see in your profile that you did not make use of a nice feature here on Stack Voerflow by now. You can mark one answer per question as solution by clicking on the checkmark under the answer score. Maybe you like to revisit your previous questions for that. And yu get 2 rep points per accept.